# How to use 'This' inside an Ajax call in angular

Tags: ajax, angular, this

I am trying to use 'this' once I get response from Ajax call.
but 'this' seems to be undefined. I found few articles using the 'bind', but I am not sure how to implement the bind.

I don't have any problem using 'this' inside the ajax call. I get response from backend as expected.

```
saveCart(data: any): void {

    let body: any = {}
    body.data = data
    body = JSON.stringify(body)
    // the 'this' works here as expected.
    let config = this.config.getHeaders() as any

    $.ajax({
      url: environment.domain + '/cart',
      type: "POST",
      headers: config,
      data: body,
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false
    }).done(function (response) {          
      // The 'this' below is undefined **********
      this.profileService.logout().subscribe(result => {   
          console.log('User was logged out', result)
      })  
    })
  }
```

Update: Couple of folks had question about why I am not using httpClient.

This function is called when the user closes the browser. Using angular angular's httpclient is freezing the browser (heavy backend code) for few seconds before it closes. so opted for ajax call.

below is the code I am using everywhere else using angular httpClient

```
  this.http.post(environment.domain + url, body, options)
      .pipe(retryWhen(this.config.handleRetry))
      .pipe(catchError(this.config.handleError))
```

Comment: If it's Angular, then for what reason are you using jQuery to make HTTP calls, instead of Angular's own HttpClient?

Comment: Can you add how you are using the httpClient? It will be a better approach than the jQuery's Ajax

Comment: Only for this particular case I have to use Ajax call. else everywhere httpClient is being used. All of them are working as expected.

Comment: Use arrow function syntax and you will have access to this.

Comment: Also, a technicality, you need to call `.pipe` only once, and you can give multiple operators like retryWhen and catchError as parameters: `.pipe(retryWhen(...), catchError(...))`

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```
saveCart(data: any): void { 
/* Other code */
var that = this;
$.ajax({ 
    url: environment.domain + '/cart', 
    type:       "POST", 
    headers: config, 
    data: body, 
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json", 
    async: false,
    success:function(response){
    //The 'this' below is undefined **********
     that.profileService.logout().subscribe(result => { console.log('User was logged out', result) })
    }
 })
```

Comment: does't work. Already tried 'that'

Comment: Have you tried success call back instead of done? Kindly check updated answer. It might be syntax error as I have updated it through mobile. So just in case syntax error kindly resolve it accordingly. 

Comment: tried success as well. Doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Can you please create one gist or fiddle and share it so that I can test it.

Comment: This normally works fine for all. So one point from my end.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this way.

**Option 1**

Before Ajax call, set a new variable...

```
var that = this;
```

Now you can user `that`     instead of this. It will work same as this.

**Option 2**

You can try with `ES6` syntax. I haven't try with Ajax but I used this in my code regularly and it works fine for me.

```
$.ajax({ 
url: environment.domain + '/cart', 
type:       "POST", 
headers: config, 
data: body, 
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: "json", 
async: false,
success:(() =>{  <----------------Hear is the change
    this...
}) =>{   
}
})
```

Comment: I shared same solution. But it doesn't work as per the person who asked the question. Personally its not possible. Might be error is at some other place. Whats your thought?

Comment: Yeah, The first solution is the same but I have also give another option. And I'm using this both on daily basis in my code.

Comment: I think it may be the some minor issue in code. I hope it may work. But don't worry our both's answer is correct. :) Happy coding.

Comment: Yo lets see what happens. 

Comment: @JavaQuest Any update on your issue ?